# Multithreading in Node.js: How to return a response from Router, but perform other operations in a separate thread?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a get route using router that needs to perform multiple time consuming operations (the duration of which usually cause Postman or whatever queries my backend to timeout). I want to return some JSON response, but then also continue to perform other operations in a separate thread. These operations will write to my database so I understand that they won't be included in the request response.

Here is my code:

```
router.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
    await querySources(req.query.id, req.query.name) // this operation takes a very long time, and has no effect on return value
    return res.status(500).json({message: "success"})
}
```

I tried putting the `querySources` call in an async block like this:

```
async () => {
    querySources...
}
```

but it never gets called

Comment: Show us your actual code and we can advise a lot more specifically.  It is unclear whether you need an actual thread or not (since asynchronous I/O is already non-blocking), but if you really want to create one, you can use the WorkerThread api.  If you show us the actual code, we can help you much, much more directly.   It appears to me that you're overthinking and overdesigning this. You probably have no issue, yet you're trying to introduce threads to solve a non-problem.  If you show us actual code, we could advise for sure.

Comment: FYI theoretical questions are far, far, far less effective here on stackoverflow, than questions that show your actual code.  Answering a question generically in a way that covers all possible situations often requires basically a chapter in a book to cover all the possibilities.  Answering a question that contains your actual code can typically be answered very specifically and accurately in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Updated with my code

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the response to wait for the database operation to complete, then you can do either of these:

```
// remove the await so you don't wait for the query to finish
router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    querySources(req.query.id, req.query.name).catch(...)
    res.status(500).json({message: "success"})
}
```

or

```
// send the response immediately, then do the database stuff
router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.status(500).json({message: "success"})
    querySources(req.query.id, req.query.name).catch(...) 
}
```

Note, you will need some ability to catch any error that `querySources()` has so that error doesn't go unhandled.  Probably you just need to log it since the client can't be notified at this point.

Answer (score -1):

well the time consuming operations you're performing should already be performed on a separate thread, assuming it's a database task you're performing you should be doing it asynchronously and it won't cause any issues for your main thread which will be listening to other requests without an issue. Also I don't see what difference creating a new thread will do (which in itself will be complicated).
The default time out for a node server is 120000 milliseconds i.e. 2 minutes, that's sufficient time for a database process to complete. Just make sure you're doing it asynchronously and not blocking the main thread.

Comment: This question is asking how to make that separate thread. I won't know if I need to perform these time consuming operations until the request is called because these operations depend on the arguments in the request body.

Comment: nodejs itself is designed to move time consuming operations to a separate thread everything that you need to do that is time consuming can be done async which would be in a different thread without you needing to worry about creating a new thread

Comment: Do you mean by something like 

`(async => {
  // do something
})`

Comment: yes thats one way if you need to await some task to complete, however I think you should post your code snippets here because creating different threads for requests is really the last thing you wanna do because node itself is powerful enough to handle time consuming operations

Comment: I don't have any snippets yet since I'm just planning this out conceptually. I understand that Node is powerful enough, but whatever called the request to my server will timeout after 2 minutes. The results of these time consuming operations aren't ever returned as a request response, they are only stored in my database. I am not creating a separate thread for each request.

Comment: @49529485 - Anything you're doing AFTER sending the response to the request won't affect the client timeout at all.  The response has already been sent, that's all the client knows about.  It appears to me that you're overthinking and overdesigning this.  You probably have no issue, yet you're trying to introduce threads to solve a non-problem.